# Problema ao passar variável de uma tela a outra

Tags: php, html, mysql

é o seguinte. Estou com um problema ao usar a $_SESSION no PHP. Estou começando agora, então me desculpem se não fiz o sistema de login do jeito correto.

Tenho uma tela de Login que executa basicamente esse código:

```
        <?php

session_start();

include_once('classes/Database.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {

    // Abre a página system.php - Outra tela, onde o nome deve aparecer.

} else {
    if (isset($_POST['form_email'], $_POST['senha'])) {
        $email = $_POST['form_email'];
        $password = md5($_POST['senha']);
        $nome = "";

        if (empty($email) or empty ($password)) {
            $error = "Todos os campos são obrigatórios!";
        } else {
            $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE u_email = ? AND u_senha = ?");
            $query->bindValue(1, $email);
            $query->bindValue(2, $password);

            $query->execute();

            $num = $query->rowCount();
            if ($num == 1) {
                // Pega o nome do usuário que logou no sistema

                $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT u_nome AS nome FROM usuarios WHERE u_id = '$num'");
                $stmt->bindValue(1, $nome);
                $stmt->bindValue(1, $num);
                $stmt->execute();

                $linha = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $nome = $linha['nome'];
                $_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                echo $_SESSION['nome'];

                header('Location: system.php');
                exit();
            } else {
                $error = 'Email ou senha incorretos!';
            }
        }

    }

    ?>

     // Aqui mostra o código html da página de login

<?php }
```

Acompanhando a estrutura do código, você percebe que se encontrou o usuário no banco de dados eu pego a variável num, passo como o ID e seleciono o nome do usuário, se eu tirar o `header('Location: ...')` ficarei na tela e mostrarei o nome do usuário, funciona perfeitamente. Veja:

[image]

Mostra o nome certinho da `$_SESSION['nome']`. Mas ao iniciar na página do `system.php` a session simplesmente parece ser apagada e dá erro de variável não definida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código system.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('classes/Database.php');

echo $_SESSION['nome']; // Aponta erro aqui, lógico

require_once './page_structure.php';

?>

// Aqui mostra o código html da página system.php
```

Se puderem me ajudar, a ideia é mostrar tipo um Bem vindo seguido do nome do usuário.

Observação: A `$_SESSION['logged-in']` mostra normal no system.php, com o valor = 1.

Comment: Você alterou o código da pergunta e agora a resposta ficou fora de sintonia. Não se deve alterar a resposta postando o código com a solução. Poste o correto  como resposta. Além do mais, do jeito que a segunda query está não precisa de `$stmt->bindValue(1, $email);` Só seria necessário se fosse ` WHERE u_email = ?");`

Comment: Voltei a versão antiga e coloquei o código atual como resposta. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolução do erro:

**Código da página de Login:**

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('classes/Database.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {

    // Abre a página system.php
    header('Location: pages/system.php');

} else {
    if (isset($_POST['form_email'], $_POST['senha'])) {
        $email = $_POST['form_email'];
        $password = md5($_POST['senha']);
        $nome = "";

        if (empty($email) or empty ($password)) {
            $error = "Todos os campos são obrigatórios!";
        } else {
            $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM cms_usuarios WHERE u_email = ? AND u_senha = ?");
            $query->bindValue(1, $email);
            $query->bindValue(2, $password);

            $query->execute();

            $num = $query->rowCount();
            if ($num == 1) {
                // Pega o nome do usuário que logou no sistema

                $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT u_nome AS nome FROM cms_usuarios WHERE u_email = '$email'");
                $stmt->execute();

                $linha = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $nome = $linha['nome'];
                $_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                echo $_SESSION['nome'];

                header('Location: pages/system.php');
                exit();

            } else {
                $error = 'Email ou senha incorretos!';
            }
        }

    }

    ?>
```

A página `system.php` permaneceu a mesma, sem alterações.

Comment: Agora melhorou, mas continuo achando que 2 querys são desnecessarias

Comment: Sou meio novato nisso. Executando 2 querys teria uma performance pior? Ou não altera muito na performance?

Comment: Claro, são duas consultas para retornar o que se pode fazer em uma consulta.

Answer (score 2):

// Pega o nome do usuário que logou no sistema

**Errado**

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT u_nome AS nome FROM usuarios WHERE u_id = '$num'");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $nome);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $num);
```

**Correto:**

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT u_nome AS nome FROM usuarios WHERE u_id = ?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $id);
```

<strike>$stmt->bindValue(1, $nome);</strike>

<strike>$stmt->bindValue(1, $nome);</strike>

Sendo que a variável `$id` você terá retornar no primeiro select

```
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$id = $row['id'];
```

> `$num = $query->rowCount();` retorna `1` caso haja algum usuário com os dados informados, portanto, se a `$query` estivesse rodando iria sempre retornar o nome do usuário com `u_id=1`

**Não vejo necessidade de duas querys para se alcançar o pretendido, bastaria uma somente.**

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('classes/Database.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {

    // Abre a página system.php - Outra tela, onde o nome deve aparecer.

} else {
        if (isset($_POST['form_email'], $_POST['senha'])) {
            $email = $_POST['form_email'];
            $password = $_POST['senha'];
            $nome = "";

            if (empty($email) or empty ($password)) {
                $error = "Todos os campos são obrigatórios!";
            } else {
                $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE u_email = ? AND u_senha = ?");
                $query->bindValue(1, $email);
                $query->bindValue(2, $password);

                $query->execute();

                $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $num = $query->rowCount();

                if ($num == 1) {
                    // Pega o nome do usuário que logou no sistema

                    $nome = $row['nome'];
                    $_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;
                    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

                    header('Location: system.php');
                    exit();
                } else {
                    $error = 'Email ou senha incorretos!';
                }
            }
       }

}

echo $error;
?>
```

Comment: Leo, fiz as alterações porém o erro persiste. Está imprimindo o nome certinho na página de login, mas se carrego o system.php dá erro.

Comment: Eu fiz uma correção na resposta, erro de digitação, estava `WHERE u_id = = ?` o correto é `WHERE u_id = ?`  Veja se foi isso

Comment: Erro persiste... Acho que é algum problema com a Session, por que na tela de login salva tudo certo, mas parece que o valor se perde e na tela de system.php dá o erro mostrado na pergunta.

Comment: Ela fecha a condição, tem código html no meio disso

Comment: Então, consegui resolver o problema. Foi simples, vou atualizar o código. Fiz outras alterações também. Foi só tirar o exit(); Não sei por que, mas resolveu

Comment: Realmente Leo, não era o exit() que estava causando o erro. Fiz uma série de testes tirando certas linhas de código e alterando e não achei o local da modificação que passou a funcionar. Vou analisar o código acima agora

Comment: Alterei o código para o atual, que está funcionando. Só Deus para descobrir esse erro, nem acredito que resolvi.